# Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o25.sessionState

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyspark

I'm trying to get hands on PySpark, so written below simple code using jupyter notebook in vscode. But few issues while trying to generate dataframe output.

I've read some where that the jars file should be on same version as SPARK and i'm using the same and install openjdk@11 on my MAC. Not sure what i'm missing here

```
import findspark
findspark.init()
import pyspark
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
spark = SparkSession.builder.master("local[1]").appName("Spark-test").getOrCreate()

data = [("Java", "20000"), ("Python", "100000"), ("Scala", "3000")]
df = spark.createDataFrame(data)
df.show()
```

**Error**

```
Py4JJavaError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[3], line 2
      1 data = [("Java", "20000"), ("Python", "100000"), ("Scala", "3000")]
----> 2 df = spark.createDataFrame(data)
      3 df.show()

File /Applications/Spark/spark-3.3.0-bin-hadoop3/python/pyspark/sql/session.py:894, in SparkSession.createDataFrame(self, data, schema, samplingRatio, verifySchema)
    889 if has_pandas and isinstance(data, pandas.DataFrame):
    890     # Create a DataFrame from pandas DataFrame.
    891     return super(SparkSession, self).createDataFrame(  # type: ignore[call-overload]
    892         data, schema, samplingRatio, verifySchema
    893     )
--> 894 return self._create_dataframe(
    895     data, schema, samplingRatio, verifySchema  # type: ignore[arg-type]
    896 )

File /Applications/Spark/spark-3.3.0-bin-hadoop3/python/pyspark/sql/session.py:936, in SparkSession._create_dataframe(self, data, schema, samplingRatio, verifySchema)
    934     rdd, struct = self._createFromRDD(data.map(prepare), schema, samplingRatio)
    935 else:
--> 936     rdd, struct = self._createFromLocal(map(prepare, data), schema)
    937 assert self._jvm is not None
    938 jrdd = self._jvm.SerDeUtil.toJavaArray(rdd._to_java_object_rdd())

File /Applications/Spark/spark-3.3.0-bin-hadoop3/python/pyspark/sql/session.py:631, in SparkSession._createFromLocal(self, data, schema)
    628     data = list(data)
    630 if schema is None or isinstance(schema, (list, tuple)):
--> 631     struct = self._inferSchemaFromList(data, names=schema)
    632     converter = _create_converter(struct)
    633     tupled_data: Iterable[Tuple] = map(converter, data)

File /Applications/Spark/spark-3.3.0-bin-hadoop3/python/pyspark/sql/session.py:515, in SparkSession._inferSchemaFromList(self, data, names)
    513 if not data:
    514     raise ValueError("can not infer schema from empty dataset")
--> 515 infer_dict_as_struct = self._jconf.inferDictAsStruct()
    516 prefer_timestamp_ntz = is_timestamp_ntz_preferred()
    517 schema = reduce(
    518     _merge_type,
    519     (_infer_schema(row, names, infer_dict_as_struct, prefer_timestamp_ntz) for row in data),
    520 )

File /Applications/Spark/spark-3.3.0-bin-hadoop3/python/pyspark/sql/session.py:342, in SparkSession._jconf(self)
    339 @property
    340 def _jconf(self) -> "JavaObject":
    341     """Accessor for the JVM SQL-specific configurations"""
--> 342     return self._jsparkSession.sessionState().conf()

File /Applications/Spark/spark-3.3.0-bin-hadoop3/python/lib/py4j-0.10.9.5-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py:1321, in JavaMember.__call__(self, *args)
   1315 command = proto.CALL_COMMAND_NAME +\
   1316     self.command_header +\
   1317     args_command +\
   1318     proto.END_COMMAND_PART
   1320 answer = self.gateway_client.send_command(command)
-> 1321 return_value = get_return_value(
   1322     answer, self.gateway_client, self.target_id, self.name)
   1324 for temp_arg in temp_args:
   1325     temp_arg._detach()

File /Applications/Spark/spark-3.3.0-bin-hadoop3/python/pyspark/sql/utils.py:190, in capture_sql_exception.<locals>.deco(*a, **kw)
    188 def deco(*a: Any, **kw: Any) -> Any:
    189     try:
--> 190         return f(*a, **kw)
    191     except Py4JJavaError as e:
    192         converted = convert_exception(e.java_exception)

File /Applications/Spark/spark-3.3.0-bin-hadoop3/python/lib/py4j-0.10.9.5-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py:326, in get_return_value(answer, gateway_client, target_id, name)
    324 value = OUTPUT_CONVERTER[type](answer[2:], gateway_client)
    325 if answer[1] == REFERENCE_TYPE:
--> 326     raise Py4JJavaError(
    327         "An error occurred while calling {0}{1}{2}.\n".
    328         format(target_id, ".", name), value)
    329 else:
    330     raise Py4JError(
    331         "An error occurred while calling {0}{1}{2}. Trace:\n{3}\n".
    332         format(target_id, ".", name, value))

Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o25.sessionState.
: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/htrace/core/Tracer$Builder
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FsTracer.get(FsTracer.java:42)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.createFileSystem(FileSystem.java:3460)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.access$300(FileSystem.java:174)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.getInternal(FileSystem.java:3574)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.get(FileSystem.java:3521)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(FileSystem.java:540)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path.getFileSystem(Path.java:365)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.internal.SharedState$.qualifyWarehousePath(SharedState.scala:282)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.internal.SharedState.liftedTree1$1(SharedState.scala:80)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.internal.SharedState.<init>(SharedState.scala:79)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.$anonfun$sharedState$1(SparkSession.scala:143)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:189)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.sharedState$lzycompute(SparkSession.scala:143)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.sharedState(SparkSession.scala:142)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.$anonfun$sessionState$2(SparkSession.scala:162)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:189)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.sessionState$lzycompute(SparkSession.scala:160)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.sessionState(SparkSession.scala:157)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.ClientServerConnection.waitForCommands(ClientServerConnection.java:182)
    at py4j.ClientServerConnection.run(ClientServerConnection.java:106)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.htrace.core.Tracer$Builder
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:581)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:527)
    ... 30 more
```

[image: Code Snipet]